# How do you debug Azure DevOps YAML file?

Tags: azure-devops

There are 3 ways to write Azure DevOps builds, as I can see it:

1. Add tasks using GUI for every little thing
2. YAML
3. A very few tasks, most of the work is delegated to Powershell. Only use tasks for things like Publish symbols or tests.

So far I am a fan of the last way because it allows me to debug most of my build logic locally. However, there are downsides:

1. Does not communicate the build structure
2. No detailed timeline

It is possible to address the latter through dedicated VSTS logging commands, but this seems tedious.

I am not considering the first option serious, because the build is not treated as code.

YAML option is very intriguing, but how do I debug it locally? So, I can debug various pieces when they call my powershell scripts, but is there a way to debug it really? Like running locally, I do not hope to place breakpoints inside the YAML, but being able to break inside the scripts (without ReadHost) would be terrific.

Answer (score 6):

In earlier agent it supports locally testing YAML configuration without queuing a build against the server, but it's internal only and according to my test it's not available now. Please refer to [YAML getting started - Run local (internal only, public preview soon)](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/d504d4ef0e82d34439aa0eb494f218c2d9146a95/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-runlocal.md) for details.

So, currently, we are unable to fully debug YAML locally. However Microsoft have added a new functionality to the [Azure Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines) extension for VSCode. Now, you will be able to create Azure Pipelines directly from VSCode without leaving the IDE.

> Enter the Azure Pipelines extension for Visual Studio Code. Now, you
> can have syntax highlighting and IntelliSense that's aware of the
> Azure Pipelines YAML format. This means that you’ll be alerted in red
> “ink” if you write “tasks:” where you should have written “task:”.
> IntelliSense is also schema-aware. Wherever you are in the file, press
> Ctrl-Space (or Cmd-Space on macOS) to see what’s accepted at that
> point in the file.

You can reference below blogs to edit/debug the YAML file with VSCode:

- [How to edit a YAML Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://www.codewrecks.com/post/old/2019/04/how-to-edit-a-yaml-azure-devops-pipeline/)
- [Using VS Code Extension for Azure Pipeline–Part1](http://chamindac.blogspot.com/2019/09/using-vs-code-extension-for-azure.html)

In addition, there's also a suggestion ticket submitted about that : [Ability to test YAML builds locally](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/366517/ability-to-test-yaml-builds-locally.html) and the state is `Under Review`. You could also go and vote it up to achieve that in future release.

[image]

Comment: This link claims public preview soon: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/d504d4ef0e82d34439aa0eb494f218c2d9146a95/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted-runlocal.md

It's from 2017. Any updates since then?